# How to remove an extension from Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, cockpit

We have discontinued Print module from Hybris and we have stopped paying maintenance for Print module. Hence, we need to remove the Print references.

I believe just removing/commenting below entries from localextensions.xml will suffice. Is there anything else I need to look at?

```
<!-- ext-print -->
<extension name="print" />
<extension name="printcockpit" />
<extension name="printhmc" />
```

Comment: Yes just comment out or remove extensions from localextensions.xml file which ever you don't want. If you would like to uninstall addons as well, in addition, you need to run `ant addonuninstall` command as well.

Comment: I think that you need to see which extensions are using it and remove it as well, because it will be included if you use an extension that depends on it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to distinguish between 'modules' and 'extensions'.

A 'module' is a set of extensions to provide some functionality to the hybris platform, for example the 'print module'.

An 'extension' is one technical hybris project that provides some functionality for a module, so here the focus is on the technical architecture.

If you want to remove (for example) the 'print module', I think you have to do the following steps:

- Look for all dependencies between the extensions for the module
- Remove them from the 'localextensions.xml'
- Do an 'ant clean all' to remove the old generated files and create only the needed ones
- Do an Update on the hybris system in the /hac to update the database to the current stand
- Look in the /hac for the 'remove orphaned types', that will delete all models that are not used anymore

So this I think are the default steps.

Comment: Also I removed the validations explicitly and constraints related to this. Thanks

Comment: Error on initiating the workflow on removing print extension. Not sure where to check it. No dependencies are found in xml files. INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/03/14 11:10:30.867 | ESC[mESC[0;33m2017-03-14 11:10:30 WARN  [Thread-17] [10.0.12.6] [EditorArea] Cound not update item, reason: [com.sbs.ecomm.hybris.sbproductcockpit.workflow.SBProductWorkflowCreationInterceptor@5d47afd3]: unexpected validator error: cannot find spring bean [workflowAssignedJobAttributeHandler] configured for dynamic attribute [Workflow.assignedJob] from extension [print]

Comment: how to remove if its in extensioninfo.xml